# HttpAddUrl on localhost fails for non-admin users

Tags: c++, http, localhost, winhttp

Using the Windows HTTP API I'm running a HTTP file server on localhost.

This involves calling `HttpAddUrl(hRequestQueue, L"http://localhost:80/", NULL)`.

This fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` unless the user runs the application as administrator.  I need this functionality for users who don't have admin privileges.  (What's wrong with a user running a localhost server anyway?  It's just for the user themselves.)

I found a [hotfix for Vista and XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939786) which seems aimed at solving this, but there's nothing for Windows 7.  The article implies it was fixed in Vista SP1, and I have Windows 7 SP1 and it's still a problem - did the fix not make it to Windows 7?

Is there anything else I can do to get the server to run for non-admins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, but found a workaround: the [IANA port numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) state ports 49152-65535 are for dynamic/private purposes.  `HttpAddUrl` for localhost on a port >= 49152 works fine for non-admins.

Comment: But `http://127.0.0.1:50000` or `http://192.168.x.y:50000` (local network address) are still required admin rights :(

Answer (score 5):

This must be configured on system level because HTTP API uses http.sys (kernel driver). You can use netsh.exe command executed with Administrator privileges to grant access to the user or application:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:80/ user=EVERYONE listen=yes delegate=no
```

Answer (score 3):

Ports `1`-`1024`, by default, require administrative access. Otherwise you get error code 5 (`ACCESS_DENIED`). If you attempt to bind to a port **above** 1024, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

it **will** work for non-admin users. In your case you tried to listen on port `80`, which HttpServer API limits to administrators.

Everything in Windows is controlled by Access Control Lists (ACLs); this includes the listen ports allowed when using HttpServer. You can display the current ACLs used by http by running:

```
>netsh http show urlacl
```

If you do that, you'll see a lot of ACLs already defined by various systems.

### Windows Communication Foundation

One ACL entry is particularly interesting:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/
   User: \Everyone
      Listen: Yes
      Delegate: No
      SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

Everyone is granted the right to listen on port `80`, as long as you live off of:

```
/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/
```

This url is used by Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), which normally constructs a URL of the form:

```
http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/{random-guid}/
```

It also means, if you *really* want port 80, you can listen with your own, for example:

```
http://localhost:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/64E3DCC6-FE47-4A86-87F4-48D2E1B44AE9/
```

As long as nobody is already using port 80 (i'm looking at your Skype!), you'll get it.

### WinSock listening sockets do not require admin

While the HttpServer API has ACLs controlling access to ports below `1024`, it should be noted that the WinSock API has no restriction.

If you want to use WinSock to open a listening socket on port `80`, you do not need to be an administrator. It is only the `Http` api that has the ACL.